# Ruby on rails table form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to display in tabular form the inputs given by the user but each time i tried to run this      code it gives me this error message "undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass". Please someone help!

```
<table width="100%">
<tr>
<th>NAME</th>
<th>REGISTRATION NUMBER</th>
<th>CLASSES ATTENDED</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<% @name_students.each do |t| %>
<td><%= t.name_student %></td>
<% end %>
<% @reg_nos.each do |t| %>
<td><%= t.reg_no %></td>
<% end %>
<% @class_nos.each do |t| %>
<td><%= t.class_no %></td>
<% end %>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Has your controller set up each instance of the instance variables you use in the view?

Comment: yes i have set up each instance in controller

Comment: Please add more informations... Add at least your controller and the exact message (line, etc.)

Comment: Could you provide your controller code then?

Comment: The most probably cause of this is that one of \@name_students, \@reg_nos, and \@class_nos hasn't been set up in the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you have not set one or more of the instance variables in the controller or they are not coming in array format, but for now, to avoid error messages you can always check whether the instance variables are nil or not, do this

```
<% @name_students.each do |t| %>
  <td><%= t.name_student %></td>
<% end unless @name_students.blank? %>
<% @reg_nos.each do |t| %>
  <td><%= t.reg_no %></td>
<% end unless @reg_nos.blank? %>
<% @class_nos.each do |t| %>
  <td><%= t.class_no %></td>
<% end unless @class_nos.blank? %>
```